# PHP form data to login with external form

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I want to make a portal where my users can login to multiple external services. I have PHP form on my own website and when my users enter the data in this form, I want it to be transferred to an external website (which I do not own or control), use the data to fill in the login form there and then redirect the user to the members-area of the external website (that I do not own or control). When I google this I get mixed results and also the answers on StackOverflow regarding this subject are a bit confusing. Is this, or is this not possible?

I reminds me of the principle of phishing, where one of my accounts was once hacked. I never noticed a thing, entered my credentials on the fake website and got transferred to the members area of the real website, that means it's actually possible right?

Thanks!
Sander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `$_POST` it to any site you want. However, once the data is received, it's out of your control.

Regarding the last paragraph in your question, what you're describing is a phishing site. The attacker owns the site and has full control over it. It's made to look like a normal site, tricking the user to enter the user credentials.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, wouldn't I have to know what the names of the fields on the external website are to make the login fields on my own website work? 

Yes, but I eventually got logged into the actual website, so somehow the credentials entered on the fake website got transferred to the legit website which is out of their control right?

Comment: Yes, you would. But that's easy to find out by looking at the HTML source. It sounds like they simply skimmed your login info and passed a `$_POST` request to the real site, thereby logging you in.